# Graph embeddings on nonorientable surfaces

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs, compact-manifolds

If a finite graph $G$ can be embedded on an orientable surface of genus $n$, does this mean that it can be embedded on a nonorientable surface of genus $n$? Is the converse of this statement true?

Comment: Non-orientable genus isn't that much similar to orientable genus ; typically an orientable surface of genus $n$ joined with a cross-cap (of non-orientable genus $1$) has a non-orientable genus of $2n+1$. Which is why non-orientable genus is sometimes called *demigenus*. So I wouldn't expect such a property, at least with these numbers.

Comment: After some googling, there are 35 forbidden minor graphs for the real projective plane where as the torus has over 1000 forbidden minor graphs, so that tells me at least one of the statements is false, if not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Hugo Manet's comment suggests, nonorientable and orientable genus don't really line up like that. Euler's formula states that

$$|V|-|E|+|F|=\chi(S),$$

where $\chi(S)$ denotes the Euler characteristic of the surface. The Euler characteristic of the sphere with $g$ handles is $2-2g$, but the Euler characteristic of the sphere with $k$ crosscaps is $2-k$. As a result, maybe the smallest case is really about comparing the Klein bottle and the torus, two surfaces with the same Euler characteristic. Both statements have counterexamples (see [Ringel, "Non-existence of graph embeddings"](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BFb0070403.pdf)):

- $K_7$, the complete graph on 7 vertices, embeds in the torus, but not the Klein bottle.
- $K_8-C_4$, the complete graph on 8 vertices with edges of a 4-cycle deleted, embeds in the Klein bottle, but not the torus.